# C#: Checkmarx Vulnerability HRA_CSHARP_Missing_XML_Validation How to fix it?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, checkmarx

I am using c# and asp.net. Checkmarx scanner is giving issue HRA_CSHARP_Missing_XML_Validation. Missing XML Validation on this line
**XmlReader xmlReader = (XmlReader)objCommand.ExecuteXmlReader();**
Storedprocedure returning data in the xml format. Please help how to fix it? GetList is called on Page Load

```
private void GetList(int intTemplate_ID)
{
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
   StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb);
   string CONTROL_TYPE = "CHECKBOX";                                                                               
   XsltArgumentList args = new XsltArgumentList();                                              
   args.AddParam("control-type","",CONTROL_TYPE);                                         

  SqlConnection objConnect = new SqlConnection(strDBConnect);
  SqlCommand objCommand = new SqlCommand( "usp_GetStates_xml", objConnect );
  objCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
  objCommand.Parameters.Add ( new SqlParameter( "@Template_ID", SqlDbType.Int, 4));
  objCommand.Parameters["@Template_ID"].Value = intTemplate_ID;
 objConnect.Open();
 XmlReader xmlReader = (XmlReader)objCommand.ExecuteXmlReader(); 
 XPathDocument xmlDoc = new XPathDocument(xmlReader);
 XslTransform xslDoc = new XslTransform();                                                     
 xslDoc.Load(Server.MapPath("xslt/liststates.xslt"));                                                        
 xslDoc.Transform(xmlDoc,args,sw,null);
 this.pnlTransformation.Visible = true;                                                           
 this.divTransformation.InnerHtml = sb.ToString();
 xmlReader.Close();
}
```

Storedprocedure returns data in xml format

```
<Product>
<states state-id="11" is-assigned="N/A">Alabama</states>
<states state-id="12" is-assigned="N/A">Alaska</states>
</Product>
```

Comment: Please help how to fix Missing XML Validation on this line XmlReader xmlReader = (XmlReader)objCommand.ExecuteXmlReader();

Comment: Please format your message, cleanup the code to contain only the relevant information, and paste the whole Checkmarx message here.

Comment: Hi baruchiro, Please help.  have formatted the message. Checkmarx scan is giving issues saying xml validation . I have even updated the package System.Text.Encoding.Web dll to latest one 4.7.2. Please help how to validate xml in c#

Comment: I assume the query is working inside SQL Server Management Studio and that is the response that you posted (not from c#).  I suspect that the query is not returning any data.  I would check the log file using SSMS to see the error inside the database when you run from c#.  The log file can be found using the SSMS explorer under management tab.  You can also check in c# if xmlReader contains any results.

Comment: Yes, thats correct. I execute the stored procedure usp_GetStates_xml in the sql server and provides the result of sql query. There are no logs inside ssms. <Product>
<states state-id="11" is-assigned="N/A">Alabama</states>
<states state-id="12" is-assigned="N/A">Alaska</states>
</Product>